# Marshalling/DllImport of Binary/Hex Data from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, dllimport

I have a C++ Header File that gives me access to two functions that, after cutting stuff that is not necessary, are this:

```
extern __declspec (dllimport) bool __cdecl GetBinary(unsigned short* _allocatedBufferSizeBufferLength, char* _receiveBuffer);
```

The _data and _receiveBuffer parameters are supposed to be binary information, not the strings as char* would initially suggest.

The reference C++ implementation I have would use the functions like this:

```
char output;
unsigned short allocatedBufferLength = 1;
GetBinary(&allocatedBufferLength,&output);
```

My Import Declaration for these two right now looks like this:

```
[DllImport( "MyDriver.dll", EntryPoint = "GetBinary", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl )]
public static extern bool GetBinary( out ushort allocatedBufferSizeBufferLength, StringBuilder receiveBuffer );
```

With this in mind, what I try to get as a result are byte[] binary arrays. This works well in most cases. However, I have byte arrays with "0" bytes right in the  middle. With the StringBuilder this will result in me only getting the first part of the array. How would I be able to reliably get the entire binary array/blob?

**Edit:** This is how I use it in my C# Method, normally I can extract the binary data from the string inside the StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder outVar = new StringBuilder( 30 );
allocatedBufferLength = (ushort)(outVar.Length - 1);
UnsafeNativeMethods.GetBinary( out allocatedBufferLength, outVar );
```

Comment: Can you show the code from where you are calling "GetBinary" function in c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The protocol for this function appears to be that the caller allocates the buffer, and passes the length of the allocated buffer to the function by reference. I assume that the function modifies the length on return to contain the number of bytes copied.

You want to change the signature to return a byte array so that you can deal with text that contains null characters. So the C# would look like this:

```
[DllImport("MyDriver.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
public static extern bool GetBinary(
    ref ushort allocatedBufferSizeBufferLength, 
    [In, Out] byte[] receiveBuffer
);
```

Note that there is no need for `CharSet` since we have switched to a byte array. There are no text parameters. And note also that `SetLastError` is for use with functions that call the `SetLastError` Windows API function. I see no evidence that yours does so. Your function returns a C++ `bool` and so we marshal it as `UnmanagedType.I1`.

To call the function we must allocate a byte array for the function to populate. For instance:

```
ushort len = 256;
byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
bool retval = GetBinary(ref len, buffer);
if (!retval)
    // handle error
// process buffer
```

Presumably the length is passed by `ref` to allow the function to tell the caller how many bytes were actually copied.

Comment: Since the answer that helped me was deleted, I used this in the declaration for the byte[] parameter:

`[MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1, SizeParamIndex = 0 )]`

Comment: The `MarshalAs` attribute you include in the comment is fine, although it can be omitted here. The answer that was deleted did not contain any code that matched your unmanaged function.

Answer (score -1):

Either you can use `IntPtr` instead of `char* _receiveBuffer` and search the memory pointer then for the string blocks terminated by a NULL terminator.
Or you could try it with `char[]` as type for `_receiveBuffer` and walk through the array of chars.

Walking through the memory when using IntPtr would be something like:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < _allocatedBufferSizeBufferLength; i++)
        {
            var b = Marshal.ReadByte(ptr, i);
            // do something here with the byte just read
        }
```

Comment: How do I access the data through the IntPtr?

edit: I mean, a short example or reference would be nice. While setting this up I tried IntPtr once, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: done. What was not working with the IntPtr? did you had a look at the memory pointed to by IntPtr? This can be done using the memory window of Visual Studio (Menu:  Debug->Windows->Memory)

Comment: Apparently I have no idea how to use an IntPtr. I get AccessViolationExceptions.
How do I actually set up the DllImport call and its usage? I tried IntPtr = new IntPtr(); with using ref, out and nothing as an addition to the IntPtr variable. The Memory Window, when trying to view "ptr" shows nothing (only question marks)

Comment: When i have a look at the parameter naming of the function, i think the _receiveBuffer parameter has the wrong type. From what i understand, that should be `char** receiveBuffer` as this function allocates memory and returns the amount of allocated memory as well as a pointer to the allocated memory. Or am i wrong?

Comment: There are other functions in the API that return longs, shorts, strings. Strings are similar, and I can fetch them by using a StringBuilder, just as I wrote in my Question. With the StringBuilder code I assume that it doesn't try to allocate any memory, I need to allocate it, it just fills it.

Comment: It's not enough to say, "use `IntPtr`". You also need to cover how the caller allocates it, and then reads the contents. But really it's way easier to allocate a byte array, for instance. You suggest using `char[]` which is closer, but fails because C++ `char` is 8 on Windows bit and `C#` char is 16 bit.